# Sorting an array with special property

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

There is an array A with the following property:

For each x,y in A, if x < y then the first appearance of x in A is before first appearance of y in A.

How can I stable sort array A in O(n) on avarage.

I'm studying towards an exam in Data Structures and I came across this question on while trying to solve past exams.

Comment: Hint: use a hash table (comparison-based sorts are Ω(n log n) even in this special case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the property of `A` you know that the first occurrences of all elements form a sorted list already. The other occurrences need to end up straight after their respective first occurrence, in input order (because you want a stable sorting).

You need to keep track of the first occurrences in a list. The later occurrences you would need to track in a hashmap from element to list of elements. Finally, you can iterate over the list with first occurrences and collect the lists from the hashmap as you go.

In pseudocode that would be something like:

```
list: List(Element)
map: Map(Element -> List(Element))

foreach x in A
    if x exists in map
        map[x].add(x)
    else
        map.[x] = [x]
        list.add(x)

result = []
foreach x in list
    result.concat(map[x])
```

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, but I think both of our algorithms suffer from the same problem: Two different elements can end up in same hash cell. Don't you think it is a problem?

Comment: @Doppelganger I'm not really sure what you mean by hash cell. Do you mean that two different elements `x` and `y` might have the same hash value? Yes, that happens, but a hash map should be robust to that, by using some more reliable equality check  (that's why in for instance Java and C# you should always override both your hashcode and equals implementation)